# jQuery Plugin to slideout text on hover?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I know I have seen something similar to this online but I don't have a good example. I was hoping there might be some sort of plug-in with the structure set I could design around.

Looking to accomplish something like this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/904456/2010-06-04_1520.swf

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

(Note: See edited example at bottom for more robust solution)

One point of jQuery is to be able accomplish just this sort of dynamic behavior easily, so I don't think you need a special plugin.  [Click here to see the following code in action](http://jsfiddle.net/7Yw5x/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="hover-area">HOVER</div>
    <div id="caption-area">
        <h1>TITLE</h1>
        <p>Caption ipsum lorem dolor 
           ipsum lorem dolor ipsum lorem 
           dolor ipsum lorem dolor</p>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#container { 
    cursor:pointer;
    font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    background:#ccc;
    margin:30px;
    padding:10px; 
    width:150px; 
}
#hover-area { 
    background:#eee;
    padding-top: 60px;
    text-align:center;
    width:150px; height:90px;
}
#caption-area { width:150px; height:27px; overflow-y:hidden; }
#caption-area h1 { font:bold 18px/1.5 Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
```

​(Important part is setting `#caption-area` `height` and `overflow-y:hidden`)

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){

var $ca = $('#caption-area'); // cache dynamic section

var cahOrig = $ca.height();
// store full height and return to hidden size
$ca.css('height','auto');
var cahAuto = $ca.height();
$ca.css('height',cahOrig+'px');

// hover functions
$('#container').bind('mouseenter', function(e) {
    $ca.animate({'height':cahAuto+'px'},600);
});
$('#container').bind('mouseleave', function(e) {
    $ca.animate({'height':cahOrig+'px'},600);
});​

});
```

Also, you should scope those variables if you were implementing this for real.

---

**EDIT:** Adapted the above to work for [multiple hovers on a page, check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/y5Wn7/).

It's a bit more intricate, but hopefully you can figure it out without an expanded explanation.

Comment: Looks really good, thanks mate! Let me play with implementing into my design and ill get back to you.

Comment: Going through this is it really necessary to have variables? Because I need it to work for multiple containers, would it make more sense to just have something nested in the div that is hidden on load and then slideOut on hover?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was talking about scoping the variables.  You'd want to set them within a generic function that handled all cases.  Let me edit my solution to handle multiple hovers.

Comment: @Fuego-DeBassi updated my solution (see end) with a better example that you should be able to apply to more situations

Answer (score 2):

Very nice example, upvoted. I am only putting this here because it seemed like a bit much for a comment.

You may wish to consider jQuery.stop() in order to prevent runaway animations. To see what I mean run your mouse pointer up and down the column of wrappers a couple times at a fast pace.

The following revision of your example JavaScript worked OK for me in FireFox 3.6. The exact page layout will determine how aggressive you have to be about selector/animation performance when closing up the caption-areas.

```
var cahOrig = $('.caption-area').height();

// So the class selector doesn't need to be run over and over
var jqCaptionAreas = $('.wrapper .caption-area');

$('.wrapper').each(function(i,obj){
    $(obj).css('z-index',9999-i);
});

$('.wrapper').bind('mouseenter', function(e) {

    // put the brakes on run-aways and close them back up
    jqCaptionAreas
        .stop(true)
        .animate({'height':cahOrig+'px'},400);

    var $ca = $(this).find('.caption-area');

    $ca.css('height','auto');
    var cahAuto = $ca.height();
    $ca.css('height',cahOrig+'px');

    $ca.animate({'height':cahAuto+'px'},400);

});

$('.wrapper').bind('mouseleave', function(e) {
    $(this).find('.caption-area').animate({'height':cahOrig+'px'},400);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, overlooked that.  Also, I think in this case using $('.wrapper .caption-area:animated') as the uncached selector within the bind function will actually be faster since it will only grab one element, but good catch regardless.